# mysql query issue: fetch latest posts

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a table for posts of users.

I am trying to get all users latest post (only 1) from posts table with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE PostedAs = 'USER' GROUP BY PostedAsId ORDER BY
CONCAT(PostedDate,PostedTime) DESC
```

It's giving me only 1 post per user, but, the problem is, it's giving me result in descending order on basis of all posts.

I want to fetch all user's latest posts.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you have two separate fields for post date and time?  Why not a single datetime field?

Comment: Why not store the posted date as a unix epoch, and then just order by that?

Comment: @helion3 One should not be using unix timestamps in MySQL except for in very specific cases. Use datetime format.

Comment: Why not? It's much better for performance, takes less space, and is timezome agnostic.

Comment: @helion3 OK say you want to query for all records for a specific date AND you want to be able to do so using an index. How do you propose to do that using unix timestamp?

Comment: The database is created a while ago. And separate columns for date and time is not an issue here.

Comment: @user3067928 It is an issue.  Without that you could easily use `MAX()` aggregation and `GROUP BY` to get your result.

Comment: @MikeBrant: ok.. What willbe the query if datetime is in same column?

Comment: @MikeBrant How do you propose using an index for `datetime`? Both are just as unique. If you have a better solution that a) can be efficiently indexed, b) is timezone agnostic (a.k.a doesn't require mysql server owners to change timezones) then I'm all ears. I have an app that logs millions of records but we had no choice to ditch datetime and I consulted a dozen people who advised an index would work on an epoch. I'll admit I'm not an expert at that level of detail

Comment: @helion3 What do you mean, how would I propose to use index for datetime?  You just add an index to the field.  Then you can do queries like `SELECT ... FROM table WHERE datefield LIKE '2014-02-07%'` which utilizes that index.  Also timezone should not be a consideration for datetimefield anymore than it is for unix timestamp.  Either way if you use a single authoritative timezone (typically the timezone configured for MySQL server), you get same result.  You can then let application layer deal with any timezone conversions.

Comment: I'm asking how is an index on a `datetime` column any more beneficial than an index on an `int` column? Our application generates the unix epoch, stores it in mysql as an int. It's wound up being much faster for us. Our customers often use mysql servers run by shared providers and they do not have the ability to modify timezones. We had no reason to use a date format string, the `int` is just as easy to convert and the app language will automatically handle localizing it. Our app typically has 5-100 million records so if there's a better way, I'm all for learning.

Comment: @helion3 Because you can't work with timestamp in any meaningful real world manner without converting it to a date beforehand. If you have no reason to ever query that unix int field in a meaningful way then perhaps that is OK to use unindexed integer field with unix timestamp there. Largely though, when people put timestamps in their table, they inevitably find themselves wanting to query against it - how many records did we get yesterday? How many records did we get last month? - and so forth. I would imagine you would find this very costly to do with your tables.

Comment: @MikeBrant I don't want to hijack this thread so let me know if you'd be open to discussing this in a discussion. We do have the field indexed but I have conflicting reports about whether or not that's useful for some as unique. The only way people query our db is through the app, which uses a range of ints for the date. i.e. `where epoch > 1xxxxxxxx` for records from the past few days (using an epoch for three days ago)

Comment: @helion3 That being said, if you did have a large table that gets millions of inserts a day and you don't ever want to query against such a timestamp field and don't want the insert performance hit of an index on the field, then I would say your approach is totally fine.  I guess my main pint was to suggest to someone learning MySQL or SQL to default to using the native datetime field formats and only use a unix timestamp for cases where you consciously make that decision.

Comment: I suppose I should have revised my suggestion to indicate a "combined" date/time field for sorting, and not necessarily call out the epoch.

Comment: @user3067928 I have provided answer below based on single datetime column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work, though I don't know if it will be quick enough.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Posts p
WHERE PostedAs = 'USER' 
  AND CONCAT(PostedDate, PostedTime) = (SELECT MAX(CONCAT(PostedDate, PostedTime))
                                        FROM Posts p2
                                        WHERE p.PostedAsId = p2.PostedAsId)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE PostedAs = 'USER' GROUP BY PostedAsId ORDER BY
CONCAT(PostedDate,PostedTime) DESC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)
{
 echo $row['post'];
}
```

What is the result of the above?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you had a single datetime field, let's call it `PostedTimestamp`, you could make your query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Posts
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT
      PostedAsID,
      MAX(PostedTimestamp) AS latestPostTimestamp
    FROM Posts) AS LatestPosts
  ON Posts.PostedAsID = LatestPosts.PostedAsID
WHERE Posts.PostedAs = 'USER'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've replicated what you described in the initial question, and I can't see what the problem is with the original concat query.

**Table looks like:-**

```
mysql> desc posts;
+------------+------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
| Field      | Type       | Null | Key | Default    | Extra          |
+------------+------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
| PostId     | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL       | auto_increment |
| PostedAs   | varchar(8) | YES  |     | USER       |                |
| PostedAsId | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| PostedDate | date       | YES  |     | 0000-00-00 |                |
| PostedTime | time       | YES  |     | 00:00:00   |                |
+------------+------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

**Data in table is:-**

```
mysql> select * from posts;
+--------+----------+------------+------------+------------+
| PostId | PostedAs | PostedAsId | PostedDate | PostedTime |
+--------+----------+------------+------------+------------+
|      1 | USER     |         22 | 1977-01-13 | 12:34:56   |
|      2 | USER     |         47 | 1977-02-13 | 00:00:00   |
|      3 | USER     |         52 | 1977-03-13 | 00:00:00   |
|      4 | USER     |          7 | 1977-04-13 | 00:00:00   |
|      5 | USER     |         47 | 1977-05-13 | 00:00:00   |
|      6 | USER     |         22 | 1977-06-13 | 00:00:00   |
|      7 | USER     |         52 | 1977-07-13 | 00:00:00   |
|      8 | USER     |         52 | 1977-08-13 | 00:00:00   |
|      9 | USER     |         59 | 1977-09-13 | 00:00:00   |
|     10 | USER     |          7 | 1977-10-13 | 00:00:00   |
|     11 | USER     |          7 | 1977-11-13 | 00:00:00   |
+--------+----------+------------+------------+------------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Running your query provided in the question**

```
 mysql> SELECT * FROM Posts
        -> WHERE PostedAs = 'USER'
        -> GROUP BY PostedAsId
        -> ORDER BY CONCAT(PostedDate,PostedTime) DESC;
    +--------+----------+------------+------------+------------+
    | PostId | PostedAs | PostedAsId | PostedDate | PostedTime |
    +--------+----------+------------+------------+------------+
    |      9 | USER     |         59 | 1977-09-13 | 00:00:00   |
    |      4 | USER     |          7 | 1977-04-13 | 00:00:00   |
    |      3 | USER     |         52 | 1977-03-13 | 00:00:00   |
    |      2 | USER     |         47 | 1977-02-13 | 00:00:00   |
    |      1 | USER     |         22 | 1977-01-13 | 12:34:56   |
    +--------+----------+------------+------------+------------+
    5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**A re-arrangement of the same query (sort of):-**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM Posts
    -> WHERE PostedAs = 'USER'
    -> GROUP BY PostedAsId
    -> ORDER BY PostedDate DESC, PostedTime DESC;
+--------+----------+------------+------------+------------+
| PostId | PostedAs | PostedAsId | PostedDate | PostedTime |
+--------+----------+------------+------------+------------+
|      9 | USER     |         59 | 1977-09-13 | 00:00:00   |
|      4 | USER     |          7 | 1977-04-13 | 00:00:00   |
|      3 | USER     |         52 | 1977-03-13 | 00:00:00   |
|      2 | USER     |         47 | 1977-02-13 | 00:00:00   |
|      1 | USER     |         22 | 1977-01-13 | 12:34:56   |
+--------+----------+------------+------------+------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

using either your own provided concat order by, or my own double order by both seem to provide the correct result for the table/data detailed above, with each user being selected once, with post date/id being the latest one posted.

I might be missing something so feel free to clarify if your schema differs significantly from what I've provided here.

On the face of it though, this problem seems to have a solution in the original question.

Good luck with your problem!

Comment: Thanks for your presentation.. The problem here is. We are not getting latest post for PostedAsId 7 as in your example. There are 3 posts for this user. For user 7, we are getting old post.

Comment: @user3067928 Would you be able to post at least a partial table schema and data set? It might help in tracking down, or clarifying, the problem. Again. Good Luck with your fix.

Comment: Ah. didn't realise you'd found a fix. Plz Ignore... :)